# Magento child theme style-m.less, etc not found

Tags: magento, less

I'm learning Magento 2 and creating a child theme based off Blank. In my web/css folder I only have a source/_extend.less and source/lib/variables/_colors.less

It should be pulling everything else from the parent theme from my understanding. But it's saying /MyTheme/en_US/css/styles-m.css and /MyTheme/en_US/css/styles-l.css are not found. How can that be? What am I doing wrong?

I had a _theme.less too in addition to the _extend.less but deleted it after I realized I misunderstood its use.

I've cleared the cache and deleted files out of pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessed

Comment: After Copy vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web dir to my custom theme working fine , hope someone will be helped

Comment: check if you theme.xml have correct Parent theme name following the naming conventions like for blank it should be Magento/blank here the str case matters

Answer (score 0):

Try and do a static deploy to fix the problem. Do this on your shell/terminal on the root of your magento site.

```
php ./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme <Use the theme name you created example myTheme/default>
```

Note this process will possibly take long.

After this process you then reload your site.